# Not able to load locator for Select in Selenium from properties file in java

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have externalized my locators in java properties file. All other locators are working fine but Select locator is not working.
I have checked with printing it by assigning to string. Its printing but while using in Select statement its not working.
When I hard code locator in Select statement it works but not with properties file.

```
 @Test(priority=2)
public void filter() {
String locator=prop.getProperty("price_dropdown");
System.out.println(locator);
WebElement price=driver.findElement(By.xpath(locator));
Select select=new Select(price);
try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String value=prop.getProperty("price");
    select.selectByValue(value);

try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     
 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("ram_filter"))).click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     
driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("processor"))).click();
```

driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("snapdragon"))).click();
}

URL-https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=samsung+mobiles&sid=tyy%2C4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_7_na_na_na&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_7_na_na_na&as-pos=1&as-type=RECENT&suggestionId=samsung+mobiles%7CMobiles&requestId=37316e2d-122b-4589-8c70-13b380fd1cfd&as-searchtext=Samsung

Comment: Pls add code and error to your question?

Comment: And you also need to share HTML code for the same, if you are not able to share the URL.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Please declare the prop as global variable and add loading properties logic in the before suite method. other wise you will face null pointer exception error.

```
@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)
public void logerere(){
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("Inputs/Log.Properties");
}
```